# iOS project won't compile because of missing OpenCV file

Tags: ios, opencv, clang, mach

[image]

I'm compiling from the Pods workspace. Using OpenCv-ios 3.0.2. It's compiled fine before I changed the bundle name. Tried cleaning and building to no avail. Thank you for any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try removing it and reinstalling.  The last time I used pods and changed the bundle name I either needed to

A. Go through the pod framework target and manually rename each instance of the old bundle name.

or

B. Remove the pod installed frameworks and call reinstall.